# Check if two Bundle objects are equal in Android?

Tags: android, bundle

I would like to check if two bundles are equal, is there any way to do that instead of checking them key by key?

Comment: Will this not work? http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#writing_equals

Comment: You can't override `Bundle` because it's `final`.

Comment: I'm so curious why `Bundle` doesn't appropriately override `equals()` method. What was the reason behind that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is one way to test if two Bundles are the same:

- Check their sizes, don't bother if they're not equal
- If both values are Bundle objects use recursion
- Because a value for a key in `one` can be `null`, make sure that both values are `null` and that the key *actually* exists in `two`
- Finally compare the matching keys' values

Code:

```
public boolean equalBundles(Bundle one, Bundle two) {
    if(one.size() != two.size())
        return false;

    Set<String> setOne = new HashSet<>(one.keySet());
    setOne.addAll(two.keySet());
    Object valueOne;
    Object valueTwo;

    for(String key : setOne) {
        if (!one.containsKey(key) || !two.containsKey(key))
            return false;

        valueOne = one.get(key);
        valueTwo = two.get(key);
        if(valueOne instanceof Bundle && valueTwo instanceof Bundle && 
                !equalBundles((Bundle) valueOne, (Bundle) valueTwo)) {
            return false;
        }
        else if(valueOne == null) {
            if(valueTwo != null)
                return false;
        }
        else if(!valueOne.equals(valueTwo))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Great method, might as well declare it `static` too. Then include it in a utils class if your project uses it a lot.

Comment: This also ought to do a null check on the Bundles themselves prior to calling bundle.size() to avoid NPE.

Comment: If both values are `bundle` and equal then the `if(!valueOne.equals(valueTwo))` test is still called, which is incorrect.

Comment: The last two `else if` can be simplified to `else if (!Objects.equals(valueOne, valueTwo))`

Answer (score 9):

I have tested [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1267661/sam)'s answer and it contains a flaw. Plus I am loving Kotlin at the moment, so here is my version.

- Again the keys sets need to be the same size
- The key sets need to have the same values
- If both values are `Bundle` then test recursively.
- Otherwise test values for equality (don't retest bundles)

Code:

```
fun equalBundles(one: Bundle, two: Bundle): Boolean {
    if (one.size() != two.size())
        return false

    if (!one.keySet().containsAll(two.keySet()))
        return false

    for (key in one.keySet()) {
        val valueOne = one.get(key)
        val valueTwo = two.get(key)
        if (valueOne is Bundle && valueTwo is Bundle) {
            if (!equalBundles(valueOne , valueTwo)) return false
        } else if (valueOne != valueTwo) return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
private static boolean equalsBundles(Bundle a, Bundle b) {
        Set<String> aks = a.keySet();
        Set<String> bks = b.keySet();

        if (!aks.containsAll(bks)) {
            return false;
        }

        for (String key : aks) {
            if (!a.get(key).equals(b.get(key))) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What if there is a `Bundle` inside `Bundle`? Use it recursively?

Comment: Yep, add one more "if" inside "for" and check whether value instance of Bundle.

Comment: adding a null check on the bundles would help prevent NullPointerExceptions

Answer (score 1):

In order to handle:

- Bundles with bundle values
- Bundles with lists of bundle values

I came up with this:

```
private static boolean equalBundles(final Bundle left, final Bundle right) {
    if (!left.keySet().containsAll(right.keySet()) || !right.keySet().containsAll(left.keySet())) {
        return false;
    }

    for (final String key : left.keySet()) {
        final Object leftValue = left.get(key);
        final Object rightValue = right.get(key);
        if (leftValue instanceof Collection && rightValue instanceof Collection) {
            final Collection leftCollection = (Collection) leftValue;
            final Collection rightCollection = (Collection) rightValue;
            if (leftCollection.size() != rightCollection.size()) {
                return false;
            }
            final Iterator leftIterator = leftCollection.iterator();
            final Iterator rightIterator = rightCollection.iterator();
            while (leftIterator.hasNext()) {
                if (!equalBundleObjects(leftIterator.next(), rightIterator.next())) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else if (!equalBundleObjects(leftValue, rightValue)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static boolean equalBundleObjects(final Object left, final Object right) {
    if (left instanceof Bundle && right instanceof Bundle) {
        return equalBundles((Bundle) left, (Bundle) right);
    } else  {
        return left == right || (left != null && left.equals(right));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One-line method:

```
 static boolean isEqualBundle(Bundle a, Bundle b) {
    return a == b || (a != null && b != null && a.keySet().equals(b.keySet()) && a.keySet().stream().allMatch(s -> Objects.equals(a.get(s), b.get(s))));
}

static boolean isDeepEqualBundle(Bundle a, Bundle b) {
    return a == b || (a != null && b != null && a.keySet().equals(b.keySet()) && a.keySet().stream().map(s -> new Pair<>(a.get(s), b.get(s))).allMatch(s -> s.first instanceof Bundle && s.second instanceof Bundle ? isDeepEqualBundle((Bundle) s.first, (Bundle) s.second) : Objects.equals(s.first, s.second)));
}
```

//Test case

```
    final Bundle a = new Bundle(), b = new Bundle(), c = new Bundle(), d = new Bundle(), e = new Bundle(), f = new Bundle(), aa = new Bundle(), bb = new Bundle(), cc = new Bundle();
    a.putString("1", "A");
    b.putString("1", "A");
    c.putString("1", "C");
    d.putString("1", null);
    e.putString("1", null);
    f.putString("2", null);


    aa.putString("2", "A");
    aa.putBundle("2", a);
    bb.putString("2", "A");
    bb.putBundle("2", b);
    cc.putString("2", "C");
    cc.putBundle("2", c);

    boolean isEquals1 = isEqualBundle(a, b); //true
    boolean isEquals2 = isEqualBundle(a, c); //false
    boolean isEquals3 = isEqualBundle(d, e); //true
    boolean isEquals4 = isEqualBundle(d, f); //false
    boolean isEquals5 = isEqualBundle(aa, bb); //false
    boolean isEquals6 = isEqualBundle(aa, cc); //false
    boolean isEquals7 = isDeepEqualBundle(aa, bb); //true
    boolean isEquals8 = isDeepEqualBundle(aa, cc); //false
```

Comment: What if there is a `Bundle` inside `Bundle`?